# How to inherit from enums?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I have two different enums:

```
enum class As(val value: String) {
    A1("a1"),
    A2("a2"),
    A3("a3"),
    Unknown("null")
}
```

and

```
enum class Bs(val value: String) {
    B1("b1"),
    B2("b2"),
    Unknown("null")
}
```

since both have a common entry, I would like to inherit enums:

```
enum class Upper(val value: String) {
    
    Unknown("null")
}
```

and then:

```
enum class As(val value: String): Upper(value) {
    A1("a1"),
    A2("a2"),
    A3("a3")
}
```

and

```
enum class Bs(val value: String): Upper(value) {
    B1("b1"),
    B2("b2")
}
```

Also I would like to use the `Upper` as a parameter in a function:

```
@Composable
fun aFunc(upper: Upper, ....) {
    when(upper){
        is As -> //..
        is Bs -> //..
        else //..
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I can not inherit from enums. Otherwise I would have to overload parameters:

```
@Composable
fun aFunc(a: As, ....) {
    //..
}
```

and

```
@Composable
fun aFunc(b: Bs, ....) {
    //..
}
```

Any **smart** solution here?

Answer (score 2):

Enum inheritance is not supported in Kotlin (and in Java it's not possible too). Let's see this example:

```
enum class Coordinates { X, Y }
enum class Coordinates3D : Coordinates { Z }

val xd: Coordinates = ... // which is a limited set of this assigment? X, Y or Z too?
```

So, is there something we can replace enums with?
Yes! Sealed classes :)

```
sealed class S(val value: String) {
    object Unknown : S("null")
}

sealed class As(value: String) : S(value) {
    object A1 : As("a1")
    object A2 : As("a2")
    object A3 : As("a3")
}

sealed class Bs(value: String) : S(value) {
    object B1 : Bs("a1")
    object B2 : Bs("a2")
}

// You can use exhaustive branching for all possible types.
fun example(s: S): String {
    return when(s) {
        // must define all possible cases of S (and all possible subcases)
        S.Unknown -> "S.Unknown"
        As.A1 -> "As.a1"
        As.A2 -> "As.a2"
        As.A3 -> "As.a3"
        Bs.B1 -> "Bs.b1"
        Bs.B2 -> "Bs.b2"
    }
}

// You can match by "subtype family" too.
fun example2(s: S): String {
    return when(s) {
        S.Unknown -> "Unknown"
        is As -> "As"
        is Bs -> "Bs"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to eliminate enums `As` and `Bs`, and create a new enum that represents the sub type (either `A` or `B`).

```kotlin
enum class SubType { A, B }
```

Then you specify the subtype as a property in the enum.

```kotlin
enum class Upper(val value: String, val subType: SubType? = null) {
    A1("a1", SubType.A),
    A2("a2", SubType.A),
    A3("a3", SubType.A),
    B1("b1", SubType.B),
    B2("b2", SubType.B),
    Unknown("null")
}
```

In your function, you check the `subType` property rather than its type.

```kotlin
fun aFunc(upper: Upper) {
    when(upper.subType){
        SubType.A -> //..
        SubType.B -> //..
        null -> //..
    }
}
```

### Bonus

However, now the built-in static method `values()` will return all enum values, rather than just `As` or `Bs`. So, we can add a new method:

```kotlin
enum class Upper(val value: String, val subType: SubType? = null) {
    A1("a1", SubType.A),
    A2("a2", SubType.A),
    A3("a3", SubType.A),
    B1("b1", SubType.B),
    B2("b2", SubType.B),
    Unknown("null");

    companion object {
        fun valuesOf(subType: SubType?): List<Upper> =
            values().filter { it.subType == subType }
    }
}
```

### Other Thoughts

It's also important to consider if inheritance is truly necessary for your problem. A little bit of duplication is better than making the wrong abstraction, and inheritance can often be a huge footgun. I recommend checking out [Code Aesthetic's *The Flaws of Inheritance*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxGOiiR9ZKg&t=140s)

Unrelated, but worth mentioning - the naming convention for composable functions is to use PascalCase, not camelCase.