# Replace Any with Kotlin generics in/out?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have several enums

```
enum class As(val value: String) {
    A1("a1"),
    A2("a2"),
    A3("a3"),
}

enum class Bs(val value: String) {
    B1("b1"),
    B2("b2"),
}
```

independent from each other. Later, I might extend these enums by `Cs` and `Ds`.... Then I create multiple lists like

```
val l1 = listOf(
    As.A1 to "Bla"
    As.A2 to "BlaBla"
    As.A3 to "BlaBlaBla"
)

val l2 = listOf(
   Bs.B1 to "Cling"
   Bs.B2 to "Clong"
)
```

I want to pass these lists to a composable function

```
calcList(l1)

calcList(l2)
```

what consumes a list:

```
fun calcList(list: List<Pair<Any, String>>){
    //..
}
```

Since [I can not inherit from enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75545507/how-to-inherit-from-enums), my task is to do this with generics.. So in Kotlin with `in` and/or `out` modifiers..

To make it more generic:

```
fun calcList(list: List<T>){
        //..
}
```

or bit more specific

```
fun calcList(list: List<Pair<T, String>>){
        //..
}
```

Comment: So you want to pass in e.g. `List<Pair<SomeEnum, String>>`? But you can already do that as is.

Comment: Can you demonstrate, with some code, where exactly are you stuck? What errors did you encounter (and when), for example? It is very unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Sweeper I edited the original post. Hope I could express it better..

Comment: If `calcList()` doesn't use the type of the enum in the return type, then I don't see how generics would help you at all. You're not going to be able to use the generic type for anything useful.

Comment: It's hard to see what you're asking. I think you tried to distill your problem too much and now it doesn't make any sense anymore.

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot inherit from `Enum<T>`, you can still use it in the parameter types.

So, the first improvement would be transforming the parameter type to `List<Pair<Enum<*>, String>>` to restrict the type to any possible `enum class`.

Then, if you need to mention the generic enum type anywhere else in the signature (like, in the return type or in another parameter type), you will need to add a type parameter to `calcList` in order to express that this should be the same type in every place it is mentioned:

```kotlin
fun <T : Enum<T>> calcList(list: List<Pair<T, String>>): List<Pair<T, String>> {
   // ... 
}
```

<sup>You don't need an `out` projection here because `List` and `Pair` declare their type parameters as covariant, which means all the usages are automatically `out`-projected.</sup>

Comment: This wouldn't work if the list were a `List<Pair<Enum<*>, String>>`, i.e. containing pairs that have different enum types. I feel like this could possibly be the case considering OP's post history.

Comment: If those are different enum types with no other common supertype, then `Enum<*>` is the best thing you have in the type system for them, isn't it?

Comment: For mixed enum types, it could work with `<T : Enum<*>` instead of `<T : Enum<T>`, so `T` gets substituted by just `Enum<*>`.

Comment: Yeah, my point is that the question is rather unclear about what the goal is.